# Optimizer.apply_gradients creating variables in tf.function

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision

I have created a neural style transfer with Eager Execution, but it does not work when I  try to turn it into a tf.function.
The error message says:

```
ValueError: tf.function only supports singleton tf.Variables created on the first call. Make sure the tf.Variable is only created once or created outside tf.function. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#creating_tfvariables for more information.
```

However, no variable is being created inside the function. Here is a simplified version of the code, which is just a neural style transfer with one image (the goal is to make the generated image look exactly like the content image):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

#Get and process the images
image = np.array(Image.open("frame7766.jpg")).reshape(1, 720, 1280, 3)/255
content_image = tf.convert_to_tensor(image, dtype = tf.float32)
# variable is defined outside of tf.function
generated_image = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(1, 720, 1280, 3)/2 + content_image/2, dtype = tf.float32)

def clip_0_1(image): # keeps image values between 0 and 1
    return tf.clip_by_value(image, clip_value_min=0, clip_value_max=1)

@ tf.function
def train_step(generated_image, content_image): #turn generated image into tf variable
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.01)
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(generated_image - content_image))
    grad = tape.gradient(cost, generated_image) 
    optimizer.apply_gradients([(grad, generated_image)]) # More information below
    generated_image.assign(clip_0_1(generated_image))
    return generated_image

generated_image = train_step(generated_image, content_image)
```

The error message points to the line

```
optimizer.apply_gradients([(grad, generated_image)])
```

I have tried to change the input of  `optimizer.apply_gradients` to `zip([grad], [generated_image])`, and every combination of lists and tuples I can think of, but the error still remains. I have also looked through https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#creating_tfvariables and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer, but neither of them shows examples where the variable is not explicitly defined.
The only conclusion that I can come to is that one of my commands (most likely `optimizer.apply_gradients`) creates a variable because of an issue in my earlier code. Is that correct?

Comment: Why are you creating the optimizer inside the training step?

Comment: @xdurch0 Creating the optimizer outside of the function fixed it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Cool, I decided to write a proper answer with the reason for the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `Adam` creates additional variables to store the momentum terms for the model variables. By creating a new optimizer every training step, these variables are also re-created, resulting in the error message.

Note that it would also be a bad idea to do this without tf.function (which would not throw an error), precisely because the momentum terms would be re-initialized at every step, instead of being accumulated properly as they should be. This is why you should create the optimizer outside the training step, one time, at the beginning of training.